# How to get the values of an array in the following connect four test in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a project for my senior programming class, and I cannot seem to find a solution to the problem I'm presented with. I need to get the values of the four consecutive numbers this finds in a multidimensional array, of six rows and seven columns.

In essence, the provided code tells me if there is or isn't a consecutive four. All I need is to find the indexes of the values in the array of the four consecutive numbers.

```
public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) {
int numberOfRows = values.length;
int numberOfColumns = values[0].length;

// Check rows
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
  if (isConsecutiveFour(values[i]))
    return true;
}

// Check columns
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
  int[] column = new int[numberOfRows];
  // Get a column into an array
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    column[i] = values[i][j];

  if (isConsecutiveFour(column))
    return true;
}

// Check major diagonal (lower part)   
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows - 3; i++) {
  int numberOfElementsInDiagonal 
    = Math.min(numberOfRows - i, numberOfColumns);     
  int[] diagonal = new int[numberOfElementsInDiagonal];
  for (int k = 0; k < numberOfElementsInDiagonal; k++)
    diagonal[k] = values[k + i][k];

  if (isConsecutiveFour(diagonal))
    return true;
}

// Check major diagonal (upper part)
for (int j = 1; j < numberOfColumns - 3; j++) {
  int numberOfElementsInDiagonal 
    = Math.min(numberOfColumns - j, numberOfRows);     
  int[] diagonal = new int[numberOfElementsInDiagonal];
  for (int k = 0; k < numberOfElementsInDiagonal; k++)
    diagonal[k] = values[k][k + j];

  if (isConsecutiveFour(diagonal))
    return true;
}

// Check sub-diagonal (left part)
for (int j = 3; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
  int numberOfElementsInDiagonal 
    = Math.min(j + 1, numberOfRows);     
  int[] diagonal = new int[numberOfElementsInDiagonal];

  for (int k = 0; k < numberOfElementsInDiagonal; k++)
    diagonal[k] = values[k][j - k];

  if (isConsecutiveFour(diagonal))
    return true;
}

// Check sub-diagonal (right part)
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfRows - 3; i++) {
  int numberOfElementsInDiagonal 
    = Math.min(numberOfRows - i, numberOfColumns);     
  int[] diagonal = new int[numberOfElementsInDiagonal];

  for (int k = 0; k < numberOfElementsInDiagonal; k++)
    diagonal[k] = values[k + i][numberOfColumns - k - 1];

  if (isConsecutiveFour(diagonal))
    return true;
}

return false; 
}

public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[] values) {    
 for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 3; i++) {
   boolean isEqual = true;        
   for (int j = i; j < i + 3; j++) {
     if (values[j] != values[j + 1]) {
      isEqual = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isEqual) return true;
  }

  return false;
  }
}
```

I would like someone to at least help me by pointing me in the right direction. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: First task: think about the return type you want to use to represent those indexes. There are various options here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to play with this until I get it. I'm going to see what I can do, I've already thought of a few - problem is implementing.

Comment: You can store the valid index in a array isConsecutiveFour when returning true.. and set the array content to -1